# What is sequential boundary of a $\delta$-hyperbolic space and how is the Gromov product extended to the boundary?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, metric-spaces

I have been reading up on $\delta$-hyperbolic spaces. But I am not getting a clear idea of sequential boundary of $\delta$-hyperbolic spaces and how the Gromov product is extended to it. Could somebody please explain it to me?

Comment: The generic name is "Gromov-hyperbolic space". $\delta$ is just a quantitative value.

Answer (score 2):

There is the beginnings of a discussion, and many references, here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gromov_boundary

The paper by Kapovich and Benakli gives a definition of the "sequential boundary".  Usually this is just called the "Gromov boundary".  If you have a more precise question feel free to ask!